# Finding out type

Tags: c++, templates, types

So I have a wrapper for the default C++ `vector`. My class is a template class like vector so it basically works with all types I want to support. Now I have one issue. I would like to add a function to my wrapper that let's me save my internally stored `vector` to file. However, the library that I am using to do this has a poor C++ interface to C functions and requires me to pass over a `void*` and an entry of a predefined list of types.

Let's say I have the class:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
    dataType type;
    std::vector<T> data;

    MyClass()
    {
        //
    }
};
```

And I have three types I want to support (e.g.):

- float: floatType
- int: intType
- char: charType

**Questions:**

- How can I get the correct type for the library in my class?
- Can it be done so that I only have compile time type checks?

Comment: You could write a simple trait to translate between types and `dataType`s, but is using a more modern serialization API an option for you? Sounds like you're in for a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need support these three types, you can use a template function with specialized implementations exactly for them:

```
template<class T> class MyClass {
  ...
  f();
};

template<> MyClass<float>::f();
template<> MyClass<int>::f();
template<> MyClass<char>::f();
```

And provide the implementations exactly for these parameters in an associated C++ file. When calling `f()` on an instance with another template parameter, the linker will complain about a missing symbol because there is no specialized implementation available.

Comment: I like this one as it really hides the C interface pretty good. Could I instead of having a linker error (which is usually not so nice) also define a default constructor with a static-assert that would give a nice clear Compile-Error?

Comment: Ok, I can just put a `static_assert` with `is_same` in my class to only allow for the three types.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to support some kinds of types T you could hide the template and provide the types you want:

```
typedef MyClass<int> MyClass_32s;
typedef MyClass<float> MyClass_32f;
...
```

After that you could write a wrapper for your c Interface:

```
void passToCInterface(MyClass_32s& dat) 
{
   callCInterfaceFunction(static_cast<void*>(&(dat.data)), INT_FLAG);
}

void passToCInterface(MyClass_32f& dat) 
{
   callCInterfaceFunction(static_cast<void*>(&(dat.data)), FLOAT_FLAG);
}

...
```